# Gridview v7 support for older api android.support.v7.widget.Gridlayout failed to instaniate

Tags: android, android-support-library

I've been trying to use the v7 support library to use a grid layout in my android project. I've seen that many people have had the same issues that I'm having but all of their fixes don't work for me. I've updated java. I've updated the latest support library. I've added the support package to the build path. I've tried dragging a gridview onto a view and allow eclipse import the package. Non of these work. I continue to get `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` failed to instantiate. I even created a test project and started with the support grid layout and the same error. Anyone have any other ideas? These are some places I've looked for help:

[Eclipse giving an error of android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout failed to instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773981/eclipse-giving-an-error-of-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-failed-to-instan)

[IntelliJ and android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468606/intellij-and-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout)

[Eclipse and Android SL GridLayout not working together - "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout could not be instantiated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816283/eclipse-and-android-sl-gridlayout-not-working-together-android-support-v7-wid)

among many others....

Here's my activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    app:columnCount="6"
    app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    app:useDefaultMargins="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/total"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="6"
        app:layout_gravity="left"
        app:layout_row="0"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="none|number"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:width="500dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button8"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button9"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button6"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonMultiply"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="Multiply"
        android:text="*"
        android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonMinus"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="3"

        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="Subtract"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonDivide"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_gravity="right"
        app:layout_row="1"
        app:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="Divide"
        android:text="/"
        android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnSpan="2"
        app:layout_row="4"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:minWidth="82dp"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPoint"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="4"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="20dip"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="."
        android:width="20dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonPlus"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="4"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="Add"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonEqueals"
        app:layout_column="4"
        app:layout_row="3"
        app:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:minHeight="82dp"
        android:minWidth="20dp"
        android:onClick="Equeals"
        android:text="="
        android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
        android:width="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button7"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_light_grey"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:minWidth="40dip"
        android:onClick="numberButtonEventHandler"
        android:text="7" />



</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

this is a snip of the project tree showing referenced libraries, dependencies, and libs all pointing to v7 gridlayout: New Edit, asked to remove one reference.

[image]

This is the exact exception I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.gridlayout.R$dimen
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:255)
    at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3028)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: nobody has any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have the v7 library imported from two different locations. Try removing the one in referenced libraries.

Comment: @RaghavSood I removed one of the references from the build path as you asked, but I still get the same error. I have now posted the exact error I receive from eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem and I fixed it by importing ".../android-sdks/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout" as "Existing Android Code Into WorkSpace".

Its project name is "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout" which is a library. Then you should "Add..." it as a library in the Project/Properties/Android/Library panel. Then it should work.
Hope this would be helpful for you.

Below is my xml:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridlayout_home"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        grid:columnCount="4"
        grid:rowCount="4" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I'm missing the `.widget` part here, means I imported the wrong project?

Comment: This is not a solution. GridLayout and GridView are different components used for totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

M also using this , i am using this as like this [image]

see this , i have added a gridlayout and that is added in my generated files, but in your case don't add gridview in generated files thats why you are faceing that problem, make build path or if you say i will send you my gridview layout , but it is auto generated when i add a gridview in design file then it download automatically and add refrence automatically, so you agin add gridview from design file and that gridlayout also in your generated files, that link your project with gridviewlayout V7...

Comment: If it's in the generated folder, shouldn't it generate by it's self? I can't copy the v7 grid layout there because when I clean the project it gets deleted.

Comment: no if you give path it in configure build path then after cleaning it will not removed

Comment: after looking at my code in Linux I see that in fact there is the support.v7.gridview in the generated code. In windows this still doesn't work but I think it's a problem with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed this but in a strange way. Also if someone can give me an explanation I'll grant them the bounty! I started playing with Virtual Box and really liked the new Fedora 18. Decided to dual boot to create an android development environment. Downloaded the combined adt with eclipse package. I created a 50GB partition in windows to share files between os's and copied my project there. Booted to Fedora and started a new android project. Copied and pasted all files from my windows project into this new one and.... Presto! Works right out of the box. No modifying the build path or anything else. I get one warning : `[2013-04-10 07:27:45 - gridlayout_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /home/craig/workspace/gridlayout_v7/bin/jarlist.cache` But the project runs in my avd without problems. What's deal with that? Why won't it work in windows but work in Linux?

Answer (score -1):

Try removing **app:useDefaultMargins="true"** or make it false.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by setting the android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar library as exported on the gridlayout_V7 project.

Comment: This is not a solution. GridLayout and GridView are different components used for totally different things.

Answer (score -1):

Me too faced same problem, fixed by adding "android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar" reference to project Library folder.

From Path:
(Android Installation)\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout\libs

To Path:
(Workspace Path)(Application name)\libs

Comment: This is not a solution. GridLayout and GridView are different components used for totally different things.