# Unable to use columnCount attribute in android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

Tags: android, widget, android-support-library, grid-layout, android-library

I am trying to use **columnCount** attribute in `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` but getting error that

Error:(2) **No resource identifier found for attribute 'useDefaultMargins' in package**

I have used `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

Answer (score 7):

Try changing :

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.package.class"
```

Update your library to

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.2.0'
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822977/gridview-v7-support-for-older-api-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-failed-to) answer.

Comment: is this answer helped ?@Manish

Comment: Good pointer .. used this specifically: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout"`